# Error while sending email with attachment through Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, xampp, localhost, send

I am trying to send an email with the attachment through Codeigniter. The problem is that it attaches the file at the run time but just sends the specified content ignoring the attachment.

I have tried uploading it in 'uploads' folder and send it along with content but it sends the msg only and displays the error mentioned below

class Email_send extends CI_Controller {

```
public function send()
{
    $file_data = $this->upload_file();
    $to =  $this->input->post('from');  // User email pass here
    $subject = 'Offer from Saremco Impex';
    $from = 'myemail';// Pass here your mail id



        $emailContent = '<!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body><table width="600px" style="border:1px solid #cccccc;margin: auto;border-spacing:0;"><tr><td style="background:#ffa500;padding-left:3%"><!--<img src="http://localhost/crud/assets/logo/eoffice_logo.png" width="300px" vspace=10 />--></td></tr>';
        $emailContent .= '<tr><td style="height:20px"></td></tr>';


        $emailContent .= $this->input->post('message');  //   Post message available here


        $emailContent .= '<tr><td style="height:20px"></td></tr>';
        $emailContent .= "<tr><td style='background:#ffa500;color: #999999;padding: 2%;text-align: center;font-size: 13px;'><p style='margin-top:1px;'><a href='http://saremcoimpex.com/' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;color: #60d2ff;'>www.saremcoimpex.com</a></p></td></tr></table></body></html>";



    $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port']    = 465;
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = 60;

    $config['smtp_user']    = 'myusername';
    $config['smtp_pass']    = 'mypass';

    $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html
    $config['validation'] = FALSE; // bool whether to validate email or not

    //$file_path = 'uploads/' . $file_name;


    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from($from);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($emailContent);
    $this->email->attach($file_data['full_path']);
    $this->email->send();
/*    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Mail has been sent successfully');
    return  redirect(base_url().'index.php/user/');*/
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();

}

function upload_file()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('resume'))
    {
        return $this->upload->data();
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}
```

}

Message: Illegal string offset 'full_path' Thats the error

Answer (score 0):

Technically that should work. Maybe your uploads are not working properly, and if display_errors() returns a string, that would be the cause of your error.